# Xcode crashes when I try to delete duplicate library in Xcode (in 'link binary with libraries')

Tags: xcode

- I have a react-native project that is running on android
- In order to build it for iOS, I cloned the repo into a Mac, ran `pod install` and opened it in Xcode
- In `Build phase -> link binary with libraries`, I see a duplicate entry (`libRCTAnimation.a`). No idea where it came from...
- When I try to delete the duplicate entry, Xcode crashes.
- The duplicate entry is causing errors in the build (ambiguous reference)

Any idea how to delete it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `Project.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`, search for those frameworks and delete duplicated/all(and add them back later) entries.

Comment: Thanks @Philip, that did it!
BTW, when is Project.xcodeproj being created?
I removed another librara from the build, but it is still in the file. As far as I know the .xcworkspace file is created when one runs 'pod install', right? What about .xcodeproj?

Comment: .xcodeproj is a main project file, all structure and most of build settings are stored here. it's there when you create a new project